# LAN behind a LAN access to Internet

Tags: routing

I work at home and have work equipment.

They are installed in the work LAN, on a switch, itself connected to a server with a DHCP server (on 10.7.37.0/24) and routing with the personal LAN.

The internet comes from a router which is a DHCP server (on 192.168.0.0/24). This LAN is for personal equipment.

Now the equipments on the work LAN can't reach the internet. I've run tcpdump at the equipment, at the work/personal LAN router, at the WAN/personal LAN router, and the remote server on the internet.

I can see the packets leaving the equipment, passing through the first router and through the second router. However I don't see them reaching the online server.

I also don't see the packets coming back from the internet.

Equipments in work LAN can ping the personal equipments just fine.

Where would be the routing issue?

Here's the network map:

```
   Device
eth0 10.7.37.2
  |
  |
eth1 10.7.37.1 (DHCP server)
   Router 1 - DHCP server for devices on 10.7.37.0/24
wls1 192.168.0.14 (DHCP client)
  |
  |
br0 192.168.0.1
   Router 2 - DHCP server for devices on 192.168.0.0/24
vlan2 xx.xx.xx.xx public internet IP
  |
  |
Internet
```

Routing table on router 1:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wls1
default via 10.7.37.10 dev eth1 metric 1
10.7.37.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.7.37.10
192.168.0.0/24 dev wls1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.14
```

On router 2:

```
default via xx.xx.xx.1 dev vlan2
10.7.37.0/24 via 192.168.0.14 dev br0
xx.xx.xx.0/24 dev vlan2  proto kernel  scope link  src 47.152.241.191
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  scope link
169.254.0.0/16 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.255.1 192.168.0.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.1
```

On device:

```
default via 10.7.37.10 dev eth0 
9.9.9.9 via 10.7.37.10 dev eth0 
10.7.37.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.7.37.20 
10.7.37.10 dev eth0  scope link 
192.168.0.14 via 10.7.37.10 dev eth0
```

Comment: To get a precise answer, you would need to provide all configurations - IP of the NICs, gateways, access control lists on the routers, NATing rules on the routers.

Comment: A simple diagram would be helpful too

Comment: Of course guys sorry. I have added some information.

Comment: Why do you have such a setup? Wouldn't it be easier to have all of the machines on the same network or to use VLAN's if you need to keep them segregated?

Comment: @joequerty I don't know it didn't seem that hard. Also I went to understand why this works and how to make it work, if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing seems to be OK and you are saying that `tcpdump` shows packets passing trough the routers R1 and R2.
Only issue i can see here is the `NAT`, you have to `SNAT` or `MASQUERADE` on R2. If its a linux box with something like:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: What is `eth0` in your example? It not in my routing tables of R2 and I don't believe it's physically plugged to the internal Network. Do you mean `br0`? Neither work :(

Comment: Also there is no `POSTROUTING` chain in `iptables -nL`, is this some kind of virtual chain that is not listed?

Comment: ```eth0``` in my example is your ```vlan2```, internet facing interface

Comment: That was it thank you so much. I guess I need to read about `MASQUERADE`. Thank you so much, I will learn something today.